# Cannot add foreign key constraint Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

1. I created a model called **Reataurant**
2. I created another model called **opening_hours**
3. **One restaurant has many opening_hours**
4. I'm trying to add **RestaurantId** column as a foreign key to the openning_hours model in a migration.
5. It gives me this error

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Why could this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reference model name must be pluralized. Change **Restaurant** to **Restaurants** under references.